# All possible routes from 8 locations

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the combinatorics are simple, but I just can't remember and find a solution.

So I have **8 locations** (A-H). It does not matter the direction. So Route **A -> B** is the same as **B -> A**. How many unique routes are there?2

Comment: Is there an underlying graph? Is any connection between locations possible? Can each location be visited multiple times? Do you have fixed start and end points? Does the route have to be a cycle?

Comment: Each location $n$ is connected to each other (except "self" so $-1$), but "direction" does not matter (so divided by 2) $n*(n-1)/2$

Comment: You need to define a "route". Does it need to go through all locations? Can it go through the same location multiple times?